# How to make 64-bit guests available in a nested VirtualBox installation on iMac 5K 27-inch?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox inside of VirtualBox.

- Host OS: OS X Yosemite
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- Both versions of VirtualBox: 4.3.28

The guest versions in VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 12.04 are only 32-bit.

How can I make 64-bit available?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the present time VirtualBox does not officially support nested virtualization, even thought one can nest a 32-bit Guest a 64-bit guest cannot be nested as VT-x is not passed through to the nested Guest and it's one of the requirements to run a 64-bit Guest, nested or not.

VMware Fusion does support some nested 64-bit Guests although off the top of my head I'd have to check the documentation to be more specific.  You can have a look [Running Nested VMs](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970) at VMware's website.